# Purpose of split termination in differential pairs

Tags: differential, high-speed, lvds

Can anyone tell me what the purpose of split termination is in a differential pair?

If you look at the LVDS article on Wikipedia, you'll see the 100 Ohm termination resistor in parallel across the two pairs. But then if you look in some datasheets for some differential interfaces, you'll see an alternative method with a connection to a reference voltage (see: https://www.semiconductorstore.com/blog/2017/From-Silicon-Labs-Timing-101-The-Case-of-the-Split-Termination/2918/)

[image]

EDIT: There is also this scheme for Stratix GX FPGAs (https://www.intel.cn/content/www/cn/zh/programmable/support/support-resources/support-centers/signal-power-integrity/sgl-general.html)

[image]

According to the above, this is to provide common mode noise suppression. To me the explanation makes sense. My questions about this are:

1. What other benefit is there to using split termination? My thought is that the split termination scheme also provides some skew compensation by allowing some current to flow into/out of the receiver.
2. If there is no skew, then wouldn't the two terminations be equivalent? I would assume the answer is yes, otherwise there would be no benefit in using split termination instead of the 100 Ohm resistor.
3. Are either of these used outside of LVDS? This is where I've looked but can't get any solid answers. I know it's not used in Ethernet, just not sure about other protocols like USB or PCIe.

Comment: Isn't what you call skew compensation rather inherent to many forms of termination?

Comment: @DKNguyen I meant to say something to the effect of "allows the two signals to have some skew while still being able to detect the signal". Also, I don't know, is it inherent to many forms of termination? That was my sense with the case above, where the cap to the reference voltage either charges or discharges to provide the required current, but its response is limited in time, thus the limits on allowed skew that can be "compensated". If this is wrong please let me know as I'd like to better understand why this particular termination is used.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking slew, not skew. If by "skew" you mean differences in arrival time then I don't see how it can do that at all.

Comment: 'drift' is probably a better word than 'skew', in this usage.

Comment: @scottbb regardless of what you want to call it, I'm referring to a mismatch between the two signals in time.

Comment: Understood. That's one of the hallmarks of differential signals: they're allowed to drift over time.

Comment: @sparaps The split termination does help with common-mode noise and may reduce radiation. But, you now need very well-matched resistors (which probably have to be sized for worst case situations that may be able to occur for any given system.) To the degree they are different, common-mode becomes differential-mode noise and probably reduces the receiver's noise immunity. A nice aspect is that the split arrangement doesn't load the differential signal. It just works to filter common-mode. So I believe you should be able to design it independently from the data rate.

Comment: @scottbb A differential receiver is supposed to be a crossing detector, at least that's what the guy who designed the world's first LVDS receiver told me personally, so in theory you would need to have a crossing of the signal edges at the same instant. So you can have drift, but not too much drift. If there is too much drift, you would need something to compensate for this, thus the connection to a reference voltage that can supply some current to compensate skew... Is this the same understanding you have?

Comment: @jonk That's all well and good and I'm not questioning that at all. It's basically the same type of circuit you might use to pass common-mode noise to ground on the input of an AC line before rectification and regulation. But I've been told by the guy who designed the very first LVDS receiver that the reason for the split termination scheme had less to do with common mode noise immunity and more to do with skew immunity (within some limit). Is that incorrect, or did I just totally misunderstand his explanation?

Comment: @jonk Another point: I was told that the 100 Ohm method works fine at low enough data rates and with perfect track length matching.... So that would imply that the reason you need split termination is to ensure you can receive the desired signal if there was some amount of length mismatch....

Comment: @sparaps Hmm. I find myself in need of a definition for "skew immunity." Intriguing question, especially considering the source. Do you feel you have a good definition in mind?

Comment: @sparaps I don't understand why you think supplying current compensates for skew when skew is a result of something like differences in cable length. How is supplying current supposed to make an edge arrive sooner or later?

Comment: Skew immunity would mean "able to read out the signal correctly in the presence of some skew". I'm just referring the allowance of some skew, allowed length mismatch, allowed phase difference, whatever you want to call it.... The signals arrive at slightly different times due to length mismatch on tracks, but the receiver can still read out the signal correctly.

Comment: @DKNguyen here is one example: https://resources.altium.com/p/differential-signaling

Referring to the 100 Ohm termination:
"This arrangement ceases to be acceptable when data rates are very high, such as 2.5 Gb/S and higher. If there is no misalignment of the two edges (skew) the circuit works fine. As soon as the two edges become misaligned in time, they no longer cross in the middle, and some current needs to flow into or out of Vref. If the Vref connection is missing the edges are eroded resulting in performance degradation."

Comment: @DKNguyen actually it says that, in the presence of skew, some current is needed to flow out/into the reference... the question is why? The sentence implies that this is required to compensate skew. Based on the original LVDS receiver designer's comments and the link I cited, this is why I think the split termination would function in this way.

Comment: I think that is just talking about preserving shifts in the common mode level when the voltage levels on both lines are not equal and opposite due to skew. But that's not really fixing skew itself as the signal still gets shifted in time and arrives at the wrong time. In a single-ended system it would be like having your ground move all over the place.

Comment: @DKNguyen sure I can see that... (EDIT: I think in that case the purpose would be to preserve the common mode level in the presence of any skew.) The other reason I see for it with regards to skew would be to preserve the signal reference voltage for crossing detection... what do you think?

Comment: @sparaps Well *technically* the receive circuitry should be detecting the voltage differences between the two lines, but unless it's isolated and floating (which it often isn't) it's probably anchored to some third reference and it certainly helps if that is stable. You don't want everything straying too far from center anyways since it could leave the bounds of valid operation for your absolute input range. I agree about preserving common-mode level at mid-range, regardless of the cause rather than compensating for skew (which would entail shifting arrival times so they line up).

Comment: @DKNguyen Great thank you for clearing it up

Answer (score 4):

The advantage of the split termination is that it provides a low impedance path to ground for common mode noise.

Differential signals see the termination resistor as the input impedance of the amplifier. Common mode signals (usually noise) do not create any voltage difference across the single termination resistor in the unsplit version. Thus, the impedance seen by common mode signals in the unsplit version is the terminal impedances of the amplifier, which are typically quite high.

In the split termination version, each line carrying a common mode signal see the resistance in series with twice the capacitative reactance as the impedance. (Twice the reactance because the two lines share the capacitor, so each line sees half the capacitance, hence twice the reactance).

By providing this low impedance path to ground for common mode signals in the form of an RC network, noise of sufficiently high frequency will be attenuated. This will help improve the common mode rejection ratio (CMRR) of the overall system at higher frequencies. At least that is the theory. Note that in the example precision resistors are used. This is important, because if the resistors are not well matched, *worse* CMRR might result.