# What is the purpose of the resistors and capacitors in this CAN interface circuit?

Tags: can

I am trying to understand what these resistors and capacitors (R66, R70, C76) and (R73, C75) doing in this circuit.  They don't seem necessary to the function of the circuit.

Any idea on what function these parts serve?

[image]

---

Added:

This design is from a schematic diagram of an industrial product. There were no design notes to help in this matter. GND_ISO1 is isolated from the circuit ground as is the supply for the CAN transceiver. There is a CAN shield but it's not connected directly.

Comment: For what purpose -- understanding an existing circuit? Is this from an app note / reference design?  Internal design?  Did it come with any design notes? How does the shown snippet fit into the overall system (particularly CANH/L and GND_ISO1 in relation to circuit or earth ground and any other relevant EMC connections -- are any tied to chassis/shield for example?)?

Comment: This design is from a schematic diagram of an industrial product. There were no design notes to help in this matter. GND_ISO1 is isolated from the circuit ground as is the supply for the CAN transceiver. There is a CAN shield but it's not connected directly.

Comment: Why did you delete the schematic?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts by removing essential parts of it, rendering posted answers obsolete. I did a rollback of the changes.

Comment: ** SEPTEMBER 12:**  Edited. Closed and reopened as close flag reason now well covered by 3 answers. || Reason given was: This question has been flagged as:
Opinion-based: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the components R66, R70 and C76, those can be used as split termination for stub nodes.

This is discussed in [NXP AN10211](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10211.pdf):

[image]
[image]

But to be frank, I never had to terminate stub nodes. The CAN standard specifies a maximum stub length of 30 cm at 1 Mbps. If you keep the stubs short, you won't need this kind of unconventional termination.

Comment: I did a rollback on the question. Edits to the question that invalidates already posted answers are not ok. If this happens please flag the question, or do an edit rollback yourself if you have (I think) >2000 rep.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for doing the rollback. I tried to do it myself, but noticed this SE has a higher rep requirement.

Answer (score 2):

R66/R70/C76 looks like a [split termination](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/590942/29811) network. It behaves the same as a single 2.42 kΩ termination resistor as far as the signal is concerned, but reduces high-frequency common-mode noise.
(But 2.42 kΩ is a very unusual value for termination. A typical cable has a characteristic impedance of about 120 Ω, so both resistors should be 60 Ω.)

An ESD protection diode like V22 is usually connected directly to ground. I guess that the circuit designer used R73 to limit the current if the bus common-mode voltage floats too far away from ground, and used C75 to allow actual ESD events to be discharged quickly.

Comment: Thank you, CL. This is unusual since the 120 Ohm (R61) termination resistor actually exists in the circuit.

Comment: It's also on the wrong side: the CMC will do more (i.e. to improve RX signal quality, not just TX) with such a network on the left side of it. But the impedance is still quite high, and doing this with a proper diff terminator (120R) is much more effective (at least at the ends of the transmission line where this can be done).  It also significantly reduces the node limit on the bus (since 20 of those in parallel equals one full termination). Likewise, C75 isn't really big enough to do a good job with ESD; it helps, but it would be better still with a larger value.

Answer (score 2):

R73 and C75 are used to make the V22 CAN protection compatible with various level of jump start.
This makes sense only for automotive purpose and on certain designs only.

From "normative" point of view, the automotive CAN lines have to cope with various surges and mistakes that could occur in the vehicle life.
The jump start simulates a wrong connection of auxiliary battery (in series instead of parallel) leading to have a 24V voltage on the battery bus.
As automotive quality guys always imagine the worst :-) , they consider that the CAN  datalines (CAN_H and CAN_L) can be short-circuited for a while with VBAT at 24V.
That's the reason why, all automotive CAN protection have a breakdown voltage (VBR) at 24V and above.

This jump start test is describe in ISO 16750 and for 12V-system battery (cars, light vehicles etc...), you have to apply 24V for 60s if I remember well.
So from a normative point of view V22, complies with the standard.

[image: ISO 16750 jump start description]

But some car makers require extra margin and consider jump stat voltage up to 28V. In that case, V22 enters in avalanche mode with a 28V DC and is not qualified for that (only transient above the VBR for TVS or ESD protection).

By adding C75 and R73 you can solve the problem. When 28 V is applied, V22 enters in conduction, the C75 voltage will increase and finally block the current. V22 can survive 28V jump start. When the situation is back to normal (nomore jump start), C75 can be discharged through R73.

This solution requires 2 additional components R73 and C75. So some vendors like STM propose CAN protection with low and high VBR(from 25V to 28V with ESDCAN series) to address all car makers' specifics without additional components.

All the surges to be applied on automotive CAN lines are described here :
[STMicroelectronics Automotive CAN protection](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/sales_and_marketing/presentation/product_presentation/group1/f5/c2/2e/77/08/25/45/b8/CAN-bus-protection-ST-ESDCAN-series/files/CAN-bus-protection-ST-ESDCAN-series.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CAN-bus-protection-ST-ESDCAN-series.pdf)
or the webinar which is more complete : [STMicroelectronics Automotive CAN protection webinar](https://content.st.com/esd-protection-of-high-speed-can-transceivers-webinar.html)

Answer (score 0):

R66, R70, C76 are there for [CAN-termination](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/industrial_strength/posts/the-importance-of-termination-networks-in-can-transceivers) (split termination config).

R73, C75 and [V22](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PESD1CAN.pdf) are used for ESD (Electronic static discharge) protection.