# How to know whether a differential transceiver is internally terminated for common mode voltage or not?

Tags: differential, emc, common-mode, termination

In a keynote by Rick Hartly titled "[What your Differential Pairs Wish You Knew](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QG0Apol-oj0)", it is suggested that especially at high speeds, it is necessary to terminate the differential pair not with one resistor, but two resistors with a capacitor going to the same reference plane as the signals. The following is the relevant slide form the presentation:

[image: presentation slide on common mode termination of a differential pair]

My issue is that I have found most IC datasheets to not include anything about the termination strategy. It is thus very hard to know what to do with the signal to ensure the design is right the first time, especially because I would like to avoid needing to include pads which are then not populated.

In a [LinkedIn post](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/anasmalas_picture-this-you-ask-an-electronics-engineer-activity-6992054289644834816-qmMR) that I created, I asked about this and it was suggested that I could find this information from IBIS models, however I could not locate IBIS or any other simulation models for the ATmega 32u4, the xPico 110 module, or its internal processor (DSTni EX).

My questions summarized:

1. how to know whether an IC is internally terminated for common mode or not?
2. If it turns out that an IC only includes a single resistor (no capacitor for common mode currents), how could the IC be externally terminated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, some possibilities:

### 0: Maybe it's irrelevant

(Zero because it's the trivial / non-answer answer.)  For example, USB and Ethernet are wholly contained standards.  You don't have to mix and match anything, just wire up standards-compliant devices and go.  Follow the wiring and layout practices given in the standards or supporting material, and it'll do whatever it does (and doesn't).

That's a purely practical statement, but one doesn't learn much this way.  So...

### 1: Many aren't

It's not clear what all interfaces you're asking about, but the AVR has USB, and the xPico has Ethernet, so I'll include those.  I'll also include a few other common standards.

USB Full Speed (and below) is a source-terminated point-to-point bus.  The receiver has no load termination.  Whatever loading is present, is whatever internal resistance, losses (may include effect from internal feedback paths i.e. Miller effect; likely negligible), and pin capacitance the receiver has.  The equivalent circuit is a pair of LVCMOS logic gate style pins, and signal levels are full 3.3V minus line losses and pull resistors.  (The receiver is still differential*, but as it doesn't have any common mode range -- ESD clamp diodes activate beyond -0.3 / 3.6V** -- it's practically just a single-wire serial link.  The differential transmission still helps keep EMI down, though.)

*Except when it's not, which is the annoying part about USB.  J/K states are unbalanced (both lines high/low).

**Or maybe they're 5V tolerant (clamped i.e. VBUS + 0.3V, or zener/snapback clamped at somewhat over 5V independent of supply voltage).

Since LVCMOS drivers have a modest source impedance (usually 30-70 ohms, but depends on scaling used on the chip), it can help to add a little series resistance -- hence the common sight of 22 ohm (or so) resistors at a USB device.  Some integrate these internally.  This also helps with noise filtering (or hurts for High Speed use!).

USB High Speed (and above) enables internal termination resistors to GND, at both ends, and a pair of current sources to deliver the high-speed data.  Thus it resembles LVDS or CML (but, again, the J/K states make a glaring exception here).

**Ethernet**

Source-load terminated, point-to-point bus.  Very specialized: DC-balanced modulation affords transformer coupling, so the media (cable) can have quite nasty voltages on it (like ESD), meanwhile communication goes on just fine.  Signal levels are similar to RS-422 (see below), but drivers are very different (thanks to the transformer in use).

**RS-422/485**

This is a point-to-point or one-to-many bus, with a low-impedance transmitter, and a high-impedance receiver.  RS-485 additionally can disable the transmitter, enabling multi-mastering.

The receivers use matched resistor dividers to sense the line voltage, allowing higher signal levels (common mode noise included) than the supply rails of the device.  The resistors do load the line somewhat, so there is a limit to how many receivers can be applied to a given bus in total.  The RS-422/485 standards give a figure for the maximum unit load (minimum resistance) per receiver.  Modern receivers often improve this, claiming some fractional-load input resistance, indicating that as many times more can be used together on one bus.

The receivers also have some capacitance of course, but this isn't too important at the typical bandwidths used (i.e. not much above 20Mbps).

Because the transmitters are low impedance, they can be placed anywhere on the bus, which is usually a linear network (i.e. a single path with no branches/stubs or loops, point-to-point in a chain between nodes), with termination resistors at both ends.  (When the transmitter is at one end, it acts as a source-load terminated bus, but the double-terminated line also means it looks the same no matter where the driver is placed, hence the signal quality is excellent in multi-master operation too.)

This also applies to derived standards, like CANbus, which is based off RS-485 but with a unidirectional driver (effectively every transmitter is diode wired-OR into the bus) to provide some bus arbitration at the hardware level (analogous to what I2C does).

**LVDS**

Low Voltage Differential Signaling uses a current source, switched differentially into the line, for transmission.  Implicit in that switch, I think, is a means of setting output common-mode voltage (which typically hovers around Vcc/2, not 0V as for USB-HS), i.e. increasing the (summed) current incrementally if (line pair) voltage falls, or decreasing if rises.  Thus some Zcm sets the CM voltage, and provides some loss (damping for CM resonances).

The receivers are basically fast comparators, usually with a generous voltage range (often rail-to-rail).  This makes them tolerant of CM noise, basically making the standard feasible.  (Compare with ECL, which has similar signal level but is single-ended so any CM noise adds directly to the signal!)  No termination, just a little capacitance, so external termination is required.  Often CM (e.g. split termination) is not employed; evidently either the transmitters have enough loss to do a good job of terminating the line in CM, or environments usually aren't noisy enough to be a problem.

There's also a multi-drop LVDS standard, with higher drive current to deal with the double-terminated bus.  This works out much as RS-485 does, but with a current-sourcing transmitter, rather than voltage-sourcing.

Termination is generally external, but some devices may provide internal termination (particularly where they're expected to be lone endpoints on the bus?), or available as an option (many FPGAs have terminators that can be enabled).

---

Of the above, USB is sometimes receiver terminated, Ethernet always is, RS-422/485 never is, and LVDS usually not, but the datasheet will say if otherwise.

### 2: Fewer terminations means more flexibilities

As illustrated above, especially the most flexible, or intentionally multi-drop, standards, tend not to include termination.  You could include CMOS logic families in this as well -- granted they're not differential, but they are transmitters and receivers all the same, and we analyze their behavior all the same, when it becomes necessary to consider transmission line effects.  The fact that these have fan-out (one transmitter can be connected to multiple receivers) is very useful for building many kinds of circuits.

Basically, read the datasheet.  If input resistance is not specified, then it's probably an open-circuit equivalent (i.e. mostly capacitance).  RS-422/485 specifies resistance, as it's low enough (10s or 100s of kohms) that, given enough in parallel, it's a significant load on the line.

Conversely, USB and Ethernet tend not to describe much of anything of their bus characteristics in the datasheet, because they're simply standards-compliant, and meet whatever the manufacturer has deemed adequate (or the trade organization managing the standard, if such exists and stipulates that certain qualifying testing be done before approving such a device, deems adequate).

RS-422/485 devices are standards-compliant, too, but they're simple enough to easily describe, and there's probably enough add-on value for doing so -- you could use a transmitter as a small H-bridge, or a complementary pair of drivers (the lines don't necessarily have to be paired!), or... who knows what.  There's more you can do with them, so it's -- I mean, who knows whether manufacturers actually consider flexibility in their offerings, but the effect is, anything you come up with that needs that logic function and physical interface, yeah, go for it.

But it's a lot harder to find alternate uses for something like USB or Ethernet, there's protocol stuff integrated that you can't reprogram, or reuse for much other than their intended purposes.

(Ethernet transformers, however..!)

### 3: As for kinds of termination...

Depends.  As all good EMC questions do.

I'm not going to go into further detail about transmission lines and DM/CM and impedance matching (actually, I've rather assumed those are topics one is already knowledgeable about -- if not, reading about them in detail is highly encouraged!), but suffice it to say there are situations where a strong CM termination helps (e.g. especially when CM filtering is required), there are situations where you can't afford to add one (e.g. there's a terminator elsewhere, you can't add much line loading so resistance is out, and bandwidth needs to remain high so you can't add much capacitance), and there are situations where you simply can't do much of anything at all (like USB, with the unbalanced J/K symbols, CM filtering is essentially impossible -- it requires fully shielded cables for good reason!).

There are also reasons you might have a modest amount of termination, rather than a full thing.  For example, EMC test equipment may employ partial termination, to reduce the worst-case impedance peaks or valleys, or full line impedance stabilization (often as a network with the CM coupled to an RF port, for emissions or immunity testing).  Similar conditions may apply inside or between equipment, though likely under more limited circumstances (like known point-to-point connections -- compare with the RS-422/485 example, not much loading/termination per node is tolerable if multiple (and especially a variable number of) nodes are expected!).

Comment: Thanks Tim, always amazingly helpful :). Learned a lot from this, but one thing id like to ask about: USB is an enclosed standard, true. Why then do I always hear that passing EMC with USB is non trivial? Was EMC an oversight during its design?

Comment: That's the shielding comments -- the cable is shielded both for immunity (has miniminal common mode range, or is N/A in the case of J/K symbols) and emissions (the differential won't be perfectly balanced, but J/K start/end packets so are emitted constantly).  The most common problem is probably faulty or erroneous grounding. I even had a case a few months ago where the USB hub on my desk was emitting some 10s mV of noise. Ended up solved with some contact cleaner and cycling the cables -- bad ground on a connector apparently!

Comment: The most common example I've seen in board design, is floating the shield/ground on some impedance (even if it's just a short trace and 0-ohm jumper, that stub length has impedance at RF!!). Which is a misapplication or misinterpretation of related figures in the USB standard itself: the lifted ground is acceptable when the board is grounded elsewhere internally, and a metallic chassis provides connector grounding (thus closing the EMI path). Doing this on a bare board just injects that noise straight into the cable.

Answer (score 2):

This is called [split termination](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/590942).

1. Capacitors typically used for split termination are much larger than 10 pF (usually between 1 nF and 100 nF), and such large capacitors cannot be built easily inside ICs. So differential receivers with internal termination never use split termination.
2. For differential signals, the two 50 Ω resistors have the same effect as a single 100 Ω termination resistor. You do not want to change the impedance of the termination, so there is not really much you can do externally. If you want to use split termination, use a receiver without internal termination.

Comment: A small capacitor can be used for high speed signals, which can be embedded into the die. I beleive 1-100 nF are either for signals that may not "idle" with enough transitions to not saturate the capacitor, or its just overkill for the sake of design ease. In either case, for some communication scheme with known characteristics, it could be possible that 10 pF are enough.

In any case, do you have evidence for "differential receivers with internal termination **never** use split termination"? If for example USB doesnt include this, wouldnt it be an EMI nightmare?

Comment: The capacitor affects only common-mode noise, so it is not related to the signal frequency.

Comment: Ok, sure. That makes sense. However, I beleive that this termination does exist inside some ICs. Do you have any proof that this is not the case?

Comment: How can I provide evidence of something that does not exist?